# How to use Sys.Date() To Extract Current Year?

Tags: r

I have manually separated my dataset (`discrete_8`) into 2 separate datasets (`data` & `data2`). `'Data'` contains the data from this current year (2021), whereas `'Data2'` contains data from previous years. Of course, this is based on the current year (2021), but I want to automate the line of code so that when the year 2022 comes, I will not have to edit the script to change 2021 to 2022. Should I use `Sys.Date()` for calling the most recent year? How would I go about incorporating `sys.date()` to partition the dataset?
Here is my code so far, where I partition the dataset:

```
data <- discrete_8 %>%  filter(PS_DATE >= as.POSIXct("2021-01-01"))#current year
data2 <- discrete_8 %>%  filter(PS_DATE < as.POSIXct("2021-01-01"))#past years
```

Here is what discrete_8 looks like:

```
 X       PS_DATE PS_NAME Control.Parameters.Cell.Return.Flow.Rate Control.Parameters.Harvest.Flow.Rate Control.Parameters.Microsparger.Total.Gas.Flow.Rate
1 0 2014-02-06 123                                      NA                                   NA                                                   1
2 1 2014-02-07 124                                      NA                                   NA                                                   1
3 2 2014-02-08 125                                       NA                                   NA                                                   1
4 3 2014-02-09 126                                      1.5                                   NA                                                   1
5 4 2014-02-10 127                                      1.5                                   NA                                                   1
6 5 2014-02-11 128                                     1.5                                   NA                                                   1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use `substr(Sys.Date(),1,4)` to get the current year. In your code you can replace `as.POSIXct("2021-01-01")` with

```
as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(Sys.Date(),1,4),"-01-01"))
```

This will give the 1st of the current year in your datetime format.

Comment: It actually returns a Datetime, not a Date. Which could be corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way I can use "as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(Sys.Date(),1,4),"-01-01"" to extract the previous year instead (2020 -01-01)? For one of my datasets, the data for 2021 have not come in yet, so I want to apply this function to the 2020 data

Comment: Yes. You may use `as.POSIXct(paste0(as.numeric(substr(Sys.Date(),1,4))-1,"-01-01"))` (this converts to numeric to subtract 1 from the year)

Answer (score 1):

There is somewhat tedious bug still present in that `trunc(Sys.Date(), "year")` does not give you Jan 01 of the current year -- it does in R-devel.

But you can build yourself a helper such as this:

```
> firstDay <- function() { d <- Sys.Date(); d - as.POSIXlt(d)$yday } 
> firstDay()
[1] "2021-01-01"
```

and you can use that to compare.  (Also, in the code you posted, `as.Date()` is simpler as you ignore hours/minutes/seconds here.)

Comment: Correct. I was about to point that that out there too and decided not too.  Life too short and all that.

Answer (score 0):

one option can be the lubridate::floor_date() function:

```
lubridate::floor_date(Sys.Date(), unit = "years")

[1] "2021-01-01"
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to subtract a year so that I get "2020-01-01" using that function?

Comment: @Tiffany your request is a bit tricky in terms of keeping it failure proof. One way to go about this can the to floor, subtract one day and floor again: lubridate::floor_date(lubridate::floor_date(Sys.Date(), unit = "years")-1, unit = "years")   One alternative but less failure prone is lubridate::floor_date(Sys.Date()-365, unit = "years")